# Hashes and Curly Braces in Ruby Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have this method in one of my view files:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn", id: "some_id" %>
```

Is this correct, or would I have to attach the curly braces around the two hashes like so:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, { class: "btn", id: "some_id" } %>
```

Comment: What did you find out when you tried it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Rails server at the moment. I'm curious with this because it mentions in Hartl's tutorial in Section 4.3.4 that if you have a hash as the last argument, curly braces are optional. But what he doesn't show is if you have hashes as the last two arguments, do you need curly braces or not.

Comment: You could check it in a Ruby REP. http://joel.franusic.com/w/page/26128430/Online-REPs-and-REPLs#Ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both your code examples are correct and work.
Your question however is not right

`class: "btn", id: "some_id"` are not TWO hashes, it is one.

So you are passing one hash as the last argument, and can safely ditch the curly braces.

Comment: I remember to be confused by this a lot when I first started with ruby   (and rails), you may want to have a look at my answer on this question, it's similar, but a bit different :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204231/rails-setting-class-and-data-tag-of-an-html-attribute-with-a-single-rails-metho/13205728#13205728

Comment: Good god, the logic is intense. Thanks for that question. I believe that will come in handy in the future.